# Device motion / motion detection on mobile browsers not working

Tags: javascript, html, accelerometer, sensors, gyroscope

I'm trying to build a site with a simple parallax effect. On a mobile I want this effect to be responsive to the device's orientation / motion. There's a fair amount of information online about using `deviceorientation` events and also using the `generic sensor api`. However, though working in Chrome on my device, these do not work on Safari or Brave.

I noticed that even the demos I've found that attempt similar things eg. [Punchmeter](https://intel.github.io/generic-sensor-demos/punchmeter/), [Parallax.js](https://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/) also don't work in Safari or Brave.

Is this kind of functionality no longer possible (presumably for security reasons). If so, when did this happen? A lot of the documentation doesn't seem to have been updated with this info. Finally, does anyone have any suggestions for a work around (is there a way to ask for permission to access the accelerometer)?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, it worked before, and yes it's true, it isn't working on Safari anymore for a [privacy reasons](https://www.macrumors.com/2019/02/04/ios-12-2-safari-motion-orientation-access-toggle/) since the version 12.2 cause the `Motion & Orientation Access` is an `opt in` feature.

It also won't be fixed in the [Parallax.js](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/) -> [here is the issue that is talking about it](https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax/issues/266).

So the only way you have to make it effectively works, is to ask the user to activate it, what *"you might UX wise not want to ask the user for gyroscope settings just for enabling a purely aesthetic minor 'nice to have' addition" - [Jonatan-r](https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax/issues/266#issuecomment-614105009)*

---

If you still want to implement it, then you could try this code found [here](https://github.com/wagerfield/parallax/issues/266#issuecomment-605434725).
*But I didn't try it yet*

```
  askPermission() {
    // feature detect
    if (typeof DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission === "function") {
      DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission()
        .then(permissionState => {
          if (permissionState === "granted") {
            window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", () => {});
          }
        })
        .catch(console.error);
    } else {
      // handle regular non iOS 13+ devices
    }
  }
```

---

To be notified : If it isn't working in other browsers like chrome, you have to be sure to try it `https` -> `localhost` won't work

Comment: To affirm, I'm testing mobile sensors on a local dev environment. Yes, you must have `https://` working on the test site, one way or another. My setup: self-signed certificate _and_ a dummy certificate authority. Testing device is Android with Chrome browser on same WIFI network. FYI, Firefox (on the Android device) seemed to be much more forgiving with regard to https; I recall seeing working gyro output early on in troubleshooting meanwhile Chrome was still giving me trouble in the same trials.